# One-liner bash command works fine as root but not as sudo [syntax issue]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I did a little command to clear Swap and it works fine as a shell script, as a one-liner from root account with or without `sudo su -c`, but not from a regular user account. I've tried lot of syntax changes, mainly around quotes and double quotes, and made use of the great ShellCheck tool. But I can't find a solution. This command was previously also clearing Ram-cache and Buffer but I will use it for production servers so I've removed this part.

Here's the working command and output, first as root then as normal user with sudo. I've made it more clear by showing command on multiple lines:

```
root@machine:~# printf '\nMemory status before cleaning:\n'; \
> free -m; printf '\n1/3 Comparing free RAM and used Swap...\n'; \
> physical=$(free|grep Mem:|awk '{print $4}'); \
> printf 'Free physical memory:\t%s\n' ""$physical""; \
> swap=$(free|grep Swap:|awk '{print $3}'); \
> printf 'Used swap memory:\t%s\n' ""$swap""; \
> compare=$(echo "$physical $swap good bad" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print $3; else print $4}'); \
> if [ ""$compare"" == "good" ]; \
> then printf 'The free physical memory is sufficient to clear the Swap.\n\n2/3 Swapoff...\n'; \
> swapoff -av; printf '\n3/3 Swapon...\n'; swapon -afv; \
> printf '\nSwap have been cleared.\n\nMemory status after cleaning:\n'; \
> free -m; printf '\n'; \
> else printf 'The free physical memory is insufficient to clear the Swap. Script ends here.\n\n'; \
> exit 1; fi

Memory status before cleaning:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15698        7827        2750         303        5119        7754
Swap:          8191          37        8154

1/3 Comparing free RAM and used Swap...
Free physical memory:   2816064
Used swap memory:       38656
The free physical memory is sufficient to clear the Swap.

2/3 Swapoff...
swapoff /dev/sda5

3/3 Swapon...
swapon: /dev/sda5: found signature [pagesize=4096, signature=swap]
swapon: /dev/sda5: pagesize=4096, swapsize=8589934592, devsize=8589934592
swapon /dev/sda5

Swap have been cleared.

Memory status after cleaning:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15698        7866        2709         305        5122        7714
Swap:          8191           0        8191



=======================================================================



user@machine:~$ sudo su -c "printf '\nMemory status before cleaning:\n'; \
free -m; printf '\n1/3 Comparing free RAM and used Swap...\n'; \
physical=$(free|grep Mem:|awk '{print $4}'); \
printf 'Free physical memory:\t%s\n' ""$physical""; \
swap=$(free|grep Swap:|awk '{print $3}'); \
printf 'Used swap memory:\t%s\n' ""$swap""; \
compare=$(echo "$physical $swap good bad" | awk '{if ($1 > $2) print $3; else print $4}'); \
if [ ""$compare"" == "good" ]; \
then printf 'The free physical memory is sufficient to clear the Swap.\n\n2/3 Swapoff...\n'; \
swapoff -av; printf '\n3/3 Swapon...\n'; swapon -afv; \
printf '\nSwap have been cleared.\n\nMemory status after cleaning:\n'; \
free -m; printf '\n'; \
else printf 'The free physical memory is insufficient to clear the Swap. Script ends here.\n\n'; \
exit 1; fi" root

Memory status before cleaning:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15698        7147        3280         272        5270        8385
Swap:          8191           0        8191

1/3 Comparing free RAM and used Swap...
Free physical memory:
Used swap memory:
bash: line 0: [: ==: unary operator expected
The free physical memory is insufficient to clear the Swap. Script ends here.
```

Would anyone here have an idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Step 1: don't use a one-liner that's so ghastly and complex.  Put the one-liner into a multi-line file.  That's what shell scripts are for.  You aren't going to be typing it all every time you run it anyway.  It's even sillier to do it when you have to worry about backslashes, single quotes, and double quotes.  It's hard enough getting that stuff right without then embedding it inside double quotes on a command line.  You have to know how many different shells are going to process the string, too.  If you're lucky, it's only one, but it is hard work getting it right, and much easier in a file.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. It works fine as a script and I usually do it this way. But I'm not allowed to deploy a script on 40.000+ servers, or I would add the script to .bash_profile as an alias.

Comment: That makes life hell for you — I'm sorry.  Good luck.  I am not going to spend time working out how to do that which should not be done.

Comment: your issue is about quoting/escaping inside double quotes. type `sudo -i` and paste the script into terminal afterwards

Comment: @alecxs Exact, that's what I did on my first example as root. But this issue would also be a way for me to learn. Understanding what's wrong would make me progress and I wouldn't cause the same issue again. I understand that it's hard and time consuming to diagnose but I still hope someone will like this challenge :)

Comment: Put your code into a function; that'll make it far easier to safely stringify (the shell can build safely quoted/escaped versions of functions for you automatically).

Comment: Consider using something like Ansible. It just uses `ssh` to connect, and it will take care of the details of copying your local script (temporarily) to the remote host.

Comment: Also, while `free` and `swap off` necessarily have to run on the remote host, none of the *other* code does. Run `free`, send the results back, and do your processing and formatting with a local script.

Comment: Also, WTF is up with all the doubled-up quotes? They just cancel each other out; writing `""$whatever""` is just the same as `$whatever` with no quotes at all.

Comment: BTW, while I personally abhor ansible (in a manner than one only can after spending years using it), running a 40,000-node cluster without _some_ kind of automated deployment tooling is unthinkable. Personally, I jumped ship to Chef (finding the extra tools it provided to justify the complexity) for a far smaller environment than this one; and these days I build systems with read-only root filesystems constructed by [Nix](https://nixos.org/).

Comment: (aside: `sudo su` is almost never needed; `sudo` itself can run a shell, you don't need `su` for the purpose. See the `-s` and `-i` options).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy double-up quotes are the result of ShellCheck analysis so I've followed the instructions to enhance the command. But while it worked great with the .sh script, it seems that this tool is not efficient with one-liners. Surely not built for this usage. Your idea of a function is very cool and works fine, I should have thought about it. Working with the community is even more fun than playing with Linux, definitely ;-P

Comment: @chepner and Charles Duffy: They also have a proprietary but very old automation tool, existing even before Ansible. But the roles are very divided in this big Internet provider company and I don't have the hands on this tool. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: So, I suspect that the shellcheck warning was about your expansions being unquoted, because the double quotes reversed the double quotes starting the `sudo su -c "...` part of your phrase. But just doubling them up makes them do nothing at all -- it fixes the warning, but only because when you do so you effectively _no longer have_ any double quotes at all; the right way to fix that warning while still nesting inside a double-quoted string would be to backslash the quotes that are supposed to be literal (`"the last word has literal double quotes around it: \"here\""`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I've learnt a lot here. I will try with backslashing the quotes to learn even more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code into a function.

```
printLines() { printf '%b\n' "$@"; }
myBigNastyFunc() {
  printLines '' 'Memory status before cleaning:'
  free -m

  printLines '' '1/3 Comparing free RAM and used Swap...'
  physical=$(free | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}')
  printLines "Free physical memory:\t${physical}"

  swap=$(free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}')
  printLines "Used swap memory:\t${swap}"

  compare=$(awk '{if ($1 > $2) print $3; else print $4}' <<<"$physical $swap good bad")
  if [ "$compare" = good ]; then
    printLines 'The free physical memory is sufficient to clear the Swap.' '' '' '2/3 Swapoff...'
    swapoff -av

    printLines '' '3/3 Swapon...'
    swapon -afv

    printLines '' 'Swap have been cleared.' '' 'Memory status after cleaning:'
    free -m

    printLines ''
  else
    printLines 'The free physical memory is insufficient to clear the Swap. Script ends here.' ''
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

After doing that, you can run it as-is with the command `myBigNastyFunc`, *or* you can tell the shell to pass its definition to `sudo`:

```
sudo su -c "$(declare -f printLines myBigNastyFunc); myBigNastyFunc"
```

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy. Great to learn a new way. I will sleep less newbie tonight than today morning ;)

Anyway it returns an error:
```
sudo su -c "$(export -f myBigNastyFunc); myBigNastyFunc"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `; myBigNastyFunc'
```
I see only 2 semicolons there. I'm not sure but I guess the compare variable caused this eroor. Maybe the way I do the compare could be made better. I will search again tonight.

Comment: @Fenyx, my bad, I wrote `export -f` where it should have been `declare -f`.

Comment: Great! Thank you!
It works fine now. Now have to understand differences between export and declare with bash man page, And also understand why you didn't need to add 'root' to the end of sudo command. Yes I'm still a noob but I'm glad to learn with your help. I'm very grateful Charles :D

Comment: I've tried with "sudo -s" as you've suggested after reading sudo man page but it makes me switch to root profile. Thanks for simplifying my printf command with this new function. I'll keep both versions as reference in my own Wiki text file. `user@machine:~$ sudo -s "$(declare -f myBigNastyFunc); myBigNastyFunc"` becomes `root@machine:/home/user#` without other output. MAN explains "If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed". So it's weird that it couldn't execute the command. But it changes nothing to the efficiency of your solution :)